# Combine CSS files into single file using NPM

Tags: npm

I have several css files in my project. I want to combine them into a single one **only via NPM** (no gulp or grunt).

I heard of ccs-merge and other node modules but didn't see any practical example.
What is the best and the easiest way to achieve it?

**Edited:**

Here is my project structure:

```
Client/
     ├──js/
         |──component1  
               ├──one.css 
               ├──one.js 
         |──component2  
               ├──two.css 
               ├──two.js 
    ├──output/
    └──package.json
```

I want to combine all my CSS files into a single file directly from the NPM script.
Here is my current package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "watchify -o Client/js/bundle.js -v -d Client/js/app.jsx",
    "build": "browserify . -t [envify --NODE_ENV production] | uglifyjs  -cm > Client/js/bundle.min.js",
    "concat-css": "css-concat  Client/js/*.css > Client/js/styles.css"
  },
```

The concat-css command doesn't work. "Failed at.... 'css-concat...'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the simplest example I could think of. Given the following project structure and files:

```
project/
├──css/
|  ├──one.css
|  └──two.css
├──output/
└──package.json
```

**project/css/one.css**:

```
.one {
  color: red;
}
```

**project/css/two.css**:

```
.two {
  text-align: center;
}
```

**project/package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "concat-css": "cat css/* > output/all.css"
  }
}
```

You can run this in your terminal:

```
$ npm run concat-css

> project@1.0.0 concat-css /path/to/project
> cat css/* > output/all.css
```

Which results in **project/output/all.css**:

```
.one {
  color: red;
}
.two {
  text-align: center;
}
```

This is obviously overly simplistic, but it should demonstrate the concept. You can pipe multiple shell commands together via [npm run scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts), and you can even call run scripts from within other run scripts.

[Here's a very good article about this topic by Keith Cirkel](http://keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/) (*No grunt or gulp needed.*)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I still can't make it work. I've updated my questions with more context.

Comment: Note that a key difference between the two examples are the relative locations of the css files. In the OP, the files are in two separate directories, so they can't be selected with the sample `cat css/*` command. Something like `cat Client/js/*/*.css` should work

Comment: It still doesn't work - I keep getting - npm ERR! missing script: concat-css

Comment: @DennisNerush It appears your npm run script is attempting to use a module name `css-concat`, is that correct? The example in my answer just uses the native OS bin `cat`. My guess is that you're not using/calling `css-concat` correctly. I'm unfamiliar with that module, so can't really help you there, but have you tried using `cat` (or something other than `css-concat`) instead?

Comment: Cat doesn't work with wildcards on Windows. Do you have another idea?